# Getting distinct objects from a list

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

Edit:
The problem is not with distinct method but how Title is coded. Comparising with StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase retruns true. Problem closed.
Here is my code:

```
var b = ret.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Title, x.Type }).ToList();
```

[image]

When I run this line with my input I get this. I want to eliminate duplicates based on Title and Type. Can you tell me where I make a mistake? Aren't these 2 objects the same based on my comparison?

Thanks

Edit:
Did more debugging. It appears that the names are different.

```
var z = ret[0].Title == ret[1].Title;
```

Checked with text comparer. It is the same. Any ideas why?
I read MyClippings from Kindle. Will test if they code Title differently.

Comment: What package are you using for the `DistinctBy`

Comment: using MoreLinq;

Comment: I haven't used MoreLinq before, but what is the result if you use a Tuple instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: The task here is to produce a *small, complete program that reproduces the problem clearly*. By producing such a program either you will figure it out yourself, or you'll have something we can look at. Right now all we can do is make guesses.

Comment: Ok, should I delete it and come back later?

Answer (score 1):

Can you share a little more code i.e the Class using my example below it works correctly:

```
    public class Test {
        public string Title {get;set;}
        public Type Type {get;set;}
    }

    public enum Type {
        Kindle
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var ret = new List<Test> {
            new Test {
                Title = "Book A",
                Type = Type.Kindle
            },
            new Test {
                Title = "Book A",
                Type = Type.Kindle
            }
        };
        var b = ret.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Title, x.Type }).ToList();

        b.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Title));
    }
```

Outputs:
`Book A`

**Runnable Version**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gi8z7j

If you change the second `Book A` to `Book B` it outputs:

```
Book A
Book B
```